# How can I make this PHP/MySQL game map more efficient?

Tags: php, mysql, game-engine

I am currently working on a grid-based game map prototype. Each "tile" is 24px by 24px and the script draws out 31 x-based tiles and 21 y-based tiles for a total of 651 tiles on the screen.

The problem I'm having is that the way I have my script going, it's making a database call for every single tile that's drawn at every page refresh, meaning it's making 651 database calls to check what the tile is and the coordinates of the tile. To me this seems obscenely inefficient.

The x and y coordinates are stored in a session variable. When the user clicks one of the directional buttons below the map, it offsets the appropriate coordinate accordingly and redraws the map.

If I were to create a game based on the logic I'm using, and playing the number game let's hypothetically say I've got 100 players playing the game at any one time and they're all browsing through the map, I would have 65,100 database calls simultaneously. That can't be good for system resources.

I am not a noob when it comes to PHP/MySQL programming as I have created and launched a few different browser-based games, however, this is my first venture into generating a map and navigating around it.

The tile map can be viewed here:

http://fordserver.com/gamemap/

The actual code for this can be found here:

http://fordserver.com/gamemap/index.txt

Can anyone recommend a good way to get this running more smoothly? You'll notice that when using one of the directional buttons that the game can take quite awhile to generate the actual map, especially if you are just visiting it for the first time.

I've tried to think of different ways to use arrays and everything else, but really, the game ***needs*** to check the database for each individual tile as I plan to incorporate functions so that it shows where a specific user currently is, or a building, etc.

I appreciate any help I can get with this.

Ricky

Comment: I came across this question while working on a similar project. I guess this game hasn't really worked out very well since the links are no longer functional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I once implemented a simple game that also used a cartesian coordinate system and had rows of data in the database for each point. I got around it simply by placing a single call along these lines:

```
$xCord=34;
$xCord=16;
// Example data


select
    ID,
    tileImage,
    xcord,
    ycord,
    otherStuff
from
    mainLocationTable
where
    abs(xCord-$xCord)<15
    and abs(yCord-$yCord)<15
```

This will give you 15 tiles either side of the player location itself. If course you can customize this to suit your needs, but the principle is the same. If you store the x,y cartesian coordinates in the database, it's easy as pie to pull out all the data you need in a single query and go from there.

As you also store the data of the player location in a session, you can simply have the code itself do further checking for details when it comes to the tile that the player is on - or use a second call to get much more detailed information for a single location.

Comment: Well that's pretty much what I'm doing already, as far as only pulling out the tiles that are showing on the screen. My database holds 10,000+ records, from 0x to 100x and from 0y to 100y, and the tiles are pulled from the database based on what is being generated from the X and Y for loops. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Ricky In your question you said "it's making a database call for every single tile that's drawn at every page refresh" and what I showed you there makes a single call for all 651 tiles?

Comment: I was just about to edit my reply with a "DOH!" comment haha. I understand what you're saying now, and yes, that makes a boat-load of sense. I'll do some working and see if I can get it to feel a little more "efficient." (I've typed efficient or the derivative of more today than I think I ever have haha) -- Thanks a lot for your tips! As simple as it is, I'm surprised I didn't think of it before.

Comment: @Ricky Happy to help. I wrote this game like ten years ago now, though I have hard-pressed getting the idea out of my head for version 2.0 for a few months now. Good luck with it! I was also going to add the other thing you can do is to use a canvas to draw the map out and simply append to it as it moves, so you don't even need to pull all the data each time, but skipping past what you already have may be more trouble than it is worth.

Comment: Eh. This is just a "prototype", something I was playing with tonight. I have the game idea in my head, and I've tried to put a map together before, but I figured I'd actually try and lay down a semi-functioning map that was more of a serious effort than what I had tried previously. Your tips are greatly appreciated! Good luck with your v2. :)